# Change ReceivedTime format on outlook using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, win32com

I am trying to write a code to extract the date and time of the last email received in my inbox to a text file. Current format of the output from my variable b is `'2020-07-18 16:53:10.444000+00:00'`. I want the format to be in this format `'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'`. Appreciate of someone could help me.

Also would be great to know what the last 5 digits (+00:00) are? I am trying to understand the default format of [ReceivedTime]

```
b = str(lastDayMessages[0].ReceivedTime)
b = dt.datetime.strptime(b, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
print(b)
```

Error:
raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '2020-07-18 16:53:10.444000+00:00' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S'

Comment: The `+00:00` at the end is the time zone (difference from UTC).

Comment: If you need a good cheat-sheet for the format codes, check out https://strftime.org/

Answer (score 1):

`strptime` converts a string to a datetime. `strftime` converts a datetime to a string.

```
b = '2020-07-18 16:53:10.444000+00:00'
b = dt.datetime.strptime(b, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z') 
b.strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
```

Output

```
'07/18/20 16:53:10'
```

Read more: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior